# Minecraft Error, java.lang.VerifyError:

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I played Minecraft just recently and decided to update some of my mods. After I updated I got this error:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 25.04.14 17:44
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 579
Exception Details:
  Location:
    net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(FJ)V @541: ifne
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 00bc 2320 b808 072a b400 bcb4 03d2
    0000010: 1303 d4b6 03da 2ab4 0375 9900 082a 23b7
    0000020: 043d 110b 44b8 0365 110b 71b8 0365 2ab4
    0000030: 00bc b401 1dc7 0011 2ab4 00bc 2ab4 00bc
    0000040: b401 21b5 011d 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 058d
    0000050: b604 9b2a 23b6 058f 2ab4 00bc b401 1d3a
    0000060: 042a b400 bcb4 02cc 3a05 2ab4 00bc b405
    0000070: 933a 0619 04b4 0596 1904 b401 2a19 04b4
    0000080: 0596 6723 8d6b 6339 0719 04b4 0599 1904
    0000090: b401 3319 04b4 0599 6723 8d6b 6339 0919
    00000a0: 04b4 059c 1904 b401 3619 04b4 059c 6723
    00000b0: 8d6b 6339 0b2a b400 bcb4 03d2 1305 9eb6
    00000c0: 049b 0336 0d15 0d05 a206 072a b400 bcb4
    00000d0: 00ff b402 f799 001f 150d b305 a2b2 05a2
    00000e0: 9a00 0d03 0404 03b8 05a6 a700 0a04 0303
    00000f0: 03b8 05a6 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 05a8 b604
    0000100: 9b03 032a b400 bcb4 0305 2ab4 00bc b403
    0000110: 08b8 080a 2a23 b705 ab11 4100 b804 a9b8
    0000120: 080d 110b 44b8 0365 2ab4 00bc b403 d213
    0000130: 05ad b604 9b2a 2315 0db7 05af 23b8 0810
    0000140: 2ab4 00bc b401 212a b400 bcb4 00ff b402
    0000150: b405 a000 0704 a700 0403 b805 b32a b400
    0000160: bcb4 03d2 1305 b5b6 049b b805 bb57 b208
    0000170: 139a 0037 b805 be9a 000f b805 c19a 0009
    0000180: b805 c499 0025 2a02 23b7 05c8 2ab4 00bc
    0000190: b403 d213 05ca b604 9b19 0523 b808 16b6
    00001a0: 05cd b808 19a7 0009 110b e2b8 0353 110b
    00001b0: 60b8 0365 2a04 23b7 05c8 2ab4 00bc b400
    00001c0: ffb4 05d0 9900 0911 1d01 b805 d32a b400
    00001d0: bcb4 03d2 1305 d5b6 049b bb05 d759 b705
    00001e0: d83a 0e19 0e18 0718 0918 0bb8 081f 2ab4
    00001f0: 00bc b402 cc19 0e23 b808 2315 0d9a 0049
    0000200: b808 262a b400 bcb4 03d2 1305 e1b6 049b
    0000210: 2ab4 00bc b402 cc19 0403 b605 e59a 0026
    0000220: 2009 9499 0020 20b8 0496 6537 0f16 0f09
    0000230: 949b 0012 160f 1405 e694 9e00 06a7 0006
    0000240: a7ff d0b8 0829 1904 b401 3314 05e8 989c
    0000250: 000a 2a19 0523 b705 ed2a b400 bcb4 03d2
    0000260: 1305 efb6 049b 2a03 23b7 05c8 110b 60b8
    0000270: 0365 2ab4 00bc b600 cdb2 05f4 b603 5bb8
    0000280: 05f9 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 05fb b604 9b19
    0000290: 0519 0403 238d b808 2cb6 05ff b808 2f57
    00002a0: 111d 00b8 05d3 b206 03b6 0606 3611 2ab4
    00002b0: 01ed 9a00 f7b8 0609 2ab4 00bc b403 d213
    00002c0: 060b b604 9b15 1199 0014 b206 0e04 bd00
    00002d0: 0459 0303 b806 1453 b802 9919 0519 0423
    00002e0: b601 7119 0e23 b606 1815 1199 0014 b206
    00002f0: 0e04 bd00 0459 0302 b806 1453 b802 99b8
    0000300: 05f9 2ab4 00bc b401 6dc6 00a0 1904 b202
    0000310: 2cb6 061c 9900 9519 04c1 024b 9900 8d2a
    0000320: b400 bcb4 00ff b403 389a 0080 1904 c002
    0000330: 4b3a 1211 0bc0 b803 532a b400 bcb4 03d2
    0000340: 1306 1eb6 049b 1511 9900 3eb2 0621 1006
    0000350: bd00 0459 0319 0553 5904 1912 5359 052a
    0000360: b400 bcb4 016d 5359 0603 b806 1453 5907
    0000370: 1912 b406 25b6 062b 5359 0823 b806 2e53
    0000380: b806 329a 0020 2ab4 00bc b400 ffb4 0338
    0000390: 9a00 1319 0519 122a b400 bcb4 016d 0323
    00003a0: b606 3611 0bc0 b803 6511 0be2 b803 5311
    00003b0: 0b44 b803 6511 0302 1103 03b8 0639 04b8
    00003c0: 063c b808 322a 2315 0db7 0664 b808 35b8
    00003d0: 0838 2a03 23b7 05c8 110b e2b8 0365 110b
    00003e0: 44b8 0353 2ab4 00bc b600 cdb2 05f4 b603
    00003f0: 5bb8 063f 9900 822a b400 bcb4 03d2 1306
    0000400: 41b6 049b 2ab4 00bc b400 ffb4 05d0 9900
    0000410: 0911 1d01 b805 d303 0303 03b8 05a6 1905
    0000420: 0423 8db8 083b b606 4536 132a b400 bcb4
    0000430: 00ff b402 f799 001d b205 a29a 000d 0304
    0000440: 0404 b805 a6a7 0014 0403 0304 b805 a6a7
    0000450: 000a 0404 0404 b805 a615 139e 000f 1905
    0000460: 0423 8db8 083e b606 4557 111d 00b8 0841
    0000470: b805 d3a7 001f 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 0641
    0000480: b604 9b19 0504 238d b808 44b6 0645 b808
    0000490: 4157 1511 9900 522a b401 ed9a 004b b806
    00004a0: 092a b400 bcb4 03d2 1306 0bb6 049b b206
    00004b0: 0e04 bd00 0459 0304 b806 1453 b802 992a
    00004c0: b400 bcb4 02cc 1904 23b6 0171 190e 23b6
    00004d0: 0618 b206 0e04 bd00 0459 0302 b806 1453
    00004e0: b802 99b8 05f9 04b8 063c 110b 44b8 0365
    00004f0: 110b e2b8 0353 b208 1399 0004 b1b8 0847
    0000500: 2ab4 007f 0f97 9a00 aa19 04c1 024b 9900
    0000510: a22a b400 bcb4 00ff b403 389a 0095 2ab4
    0000520: 00bc b401 6dc6 008b 1904 b202 2cb6 061c
    0000530: 9a00 8019 04c0 024b 3a12 110b c0b8 0353
    0000540: 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 061e b604 9b15 1199
    0000550: 003e b206 2110 06bd 0004 5903 1905 5359
    0000560: 0419 1253 5905 2ab4 00bc b401 6d53 5906
    0000570: 03b8 0614 5359 0719 12b4 0625 b606 2b53
    0000580: 5908 23b8 062e 53b8 0632 9a00 202a b400
    0000590: bcb4 00ff b403 389a 0013 1905 1912 2ab4
    00005a0: 00bc b401 6d03 23b6 0636 110b c0b8 0365
    00005b0: 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 0647 b604 9b11 0be2
    00005c0: b803 6511 0302 04b8 0639 1905 b205 3a19
    00005d0: 0423 b606 4b11 0be2 b803 532a b400 bcb4
    00005e0: 03d2 1306 4db6 049b 2a23 b808 4ab6 0650
    00005f0: b808 4d11 0b60 b803 53b8 0850 1904 b401
    0000600: 3314 05e8 979b 000a 2a19 0523 b705 ed2a
    0000610: 238d b603 3c2a b400 bcb4 03d2 1306 52b6
    0000620: 049b b806 0919 0619 0423 b808 53b6 0656
    0000630: b805 f92a 0323 b705 c82a b400 bcb4 03d2
    0000640: 1306 58b6 049b 1906 1904 23b8 0856 b606
    0000650: 5bb8 0859 2a23 8db6 0342 1511 9900 262a
    0000660: b400 bcb4 03d2 1306 5db6 049b b206 6005
    0000670: bd00 0459 0319 0553 5904 23b8 062e 53b8
    0000680: 0299 2ab4 00bc b403 d213 0662 b604 9b2a
    0000690: b808 5cb4 007f 0f97 9a00 1611 0100 b804
    00006a0: a92a 2315 0db8 085f b706 64b8 0862 b808
    00006b0: 652a b400 bcb4 00ff b402 f79a 000e 2ab4
    00006c0: 00bc b403 d2b6 0440 b184 0d01 a7f9 f904
    00006d0: 0404 03b8 05a6 2ab4 00bc b403 d2b6 0440
    00006e0: b1                                    
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@34)
    same_frame(@70)
    full_frame(@197,{Object[#2],Float,Long,Object[#295],Object[#718],Object[#1440],Double,Double,Double,Integer},{})
    same_frame(@237)
    same_frame(@244)
    same_locals_1_stack_item_extended(@345,Object[#481])
    full_frame(@346,{Object[#2],Float,Long,Object[#295],Object[#718],Object[#1440],Double,Double,Double,Integer},{Object[#481],Integer})
    same_frame(@390)
    same_frame(@424)
    same_frame(@430)
    same_frame(@461)
    append_frame(@528,Object[#1495])
    append_frame(@576,Long)
    chop_frame(@582,1)
    same_frame(@601)
    append_frame(@731,Top,Top,Integer)
    same_frame(@767)
    append_frame(@902,Object[#587])
    same_frame(@931)
    chop_frame(@937,1)
    same_frame_extended(@1047)
    append_frame(@1096,Top,Integer)
    same_frame(@1106)
    same_frame(@1113)
    same_frame(@1130)
    chop_frame(@1142,2)
    same_frame(@1170)
    same_frame_extended(@1254)
    same_frame(@1277)
    append_frame(@1421,Object[#587])
    same_frame(@1450)
    chop_frame(@1456,1)
    same_frame_extended(@1551)
    same_frame_extended(@1666)
    same_frame(@1710)
    same_frame(@1737)
    full_frame(@1743,{Object[#2],Float,Long,Object[#295],Object[#718],Object[#1440],Double,Double,Double,Integer},{})

        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:487)
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:808)
        at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:487)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
        at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:808)
        at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)

-- System Details --
Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.6.4
        Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
        Java Version: 1.7.0_55, Oracle Corporation
        Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
        Memory: 138143024 bytes (131 MB) / 1382547456 bytes (1318 MB) up to 4772069376 bytes (4551 MB)
        JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx5G
        AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
        Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
        IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
        FML: MCP v8.11 FML v6.4.49.965 Minecraft Forge 9.11.1.965 Optifine OptiFine_1.6.4_HD_C9 62 mods loaded, 62 mods active
        mcp{8.09} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        FML{6.4.49.965} [Forge Mod Loader] (minecraftforge-9.11.1.965.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Forge{9.11.1.965} [Minecraft Forge] (minecraftforge-9.11.1.965.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        AppliedEnergistics-Core{rv14.finale3} [AppliedEnergistics Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        CodeChickenCore{0.9.0.9} [CodeChicken Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Micdoodlecore{} [Micdoodle8 Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        NotEnoughItems{1.6.1.9} [Not Enough Items] (NotEnoughItems 1.6.1.9.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        modJ_StarMinerCore{0.9.6} [StarMinerCore] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        TConstruct-Preloader{0.0.1} [Tinkers Corestruct] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        DamageIndicatorsMod{2.9.1.6} [Damage Indicators] (1.6.4 DamageIndicatorsv2.9.1.6.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        LumberJack{1.6.4b} [LumberJack] ([1.6.4][c][forge]LumberJack.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        mod_ReiMinimap{v3.4_01 [1.6.2]} [mod_ReiMinimap] ([1.6.4]ReiMinimap_v3.4_01.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        AppliedEnergistics{rv14.finale3} [Applied Energistics] (appeng-rv14-finale3-mc16x.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ArchimedesShipsMod{1.6.2 v1.4.4} [Archimedes' Ships] (Archimedes-Ships-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Backpack{1.26.29} [Backpack] (backpack-1.26.29-1.6.x.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BiblioCraft{1.5.4} [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft[v1.5.4].zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Natura{2.1.12} [Natura] (Natura_1.6.4_2.1.13.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BiomesOPlenty{1.2.1} [Biomes O' Plenty] (BiomesOPlenty-universal-1.6.4-1.2.1.434.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BuildCraft|Core{4.2.2} [BuildCraft] (BUILDCRAFT-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BuildCraft|Builders{4.2.2} [BC Builders] (BUILDCRAFT-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BuildCraft|Energy{4.2.2} [BC Energy] (BUILDCRAFT-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BuildCraft|Factory{4.2.2} [BC Factory] (BUILDCRAFT-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BuildCraft|Transport{4.2.2} [BC Transport] (BUILDCRAFT-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        BuildCraft|Silicon{4.2.2} [BC Silicon] (BUILDCRAFT-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Additional-Buildcraft-Objects{1.0.7.558} [Additional Buildcraft Objects] (buildcraft-Z-additional-buildcraft-objects-1.0.7.558.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        UniversalElectricity{3.1.0} [Universal Electricity] (Universal-Electricity-3.1.0.66-core.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        CalclaviaCore{1.1.1} [Calclavia] (Calclavia Core-1.1.1.196-main.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ChickenChunks{1.3.3.4} [ChickenChunks] (ChickenChunks 1.3.3.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Chisel{1.4.9} [Chisel] (chisel-1.6.4-1.4.9.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        CrossbowMod2{a0.1.6} [Crossbow Mod 2] (Crossbow-Mod-2-1.6.4-a0.1.6.33.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        dimdoors{1.6.2R2.1.1RC1} [Dimensional Doors] (DimensionalDoors-1.6.2R2.1.1RC1-8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        EnderStorage{1.4.3.6} [EnderStorage] (EnderStorage 1.4.3.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ExtrabiomesXL{3.15.7} [ExtrabiomesXL] (ExtrabiomesXL-universal-1.6.4-3.15.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        guilib{1.0.6.1} [GUI Library] (Forge_GuiLibv1.0.6.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        IC2{2.0.357-experimental} [IndustrialCraft 2] (industrialcraft-2_2.0.357-experimental.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        GalacticraftCore{2.0.12} [Galacticraft Core] (Galacticraft-1.6.4-2.0.12.1010.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        GalacticraftMars{2.0.12} [Galacticraft Mars] (Galacticraft-Planets-1.6.4-2.0.12.1010.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Mekanism{6.0.4} [Mekanism] (Mekanism-6.0.4.35.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        MekanismGenerators{6.0.4} [MekanismGenerators] (MekanismGenerators-6.0.4.35.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        MekanismTools{6.0.4} [MekanismTools] (MekanismTools-6.0.4.35.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        AdvancedSolarPanel{3.4.7} [Advanced Solar Panels] (mod_AdvancedSolarPanels_3_4_7_IC_EXP.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        More Pistons{1.4.1 [Build Smeagol]} [More Pistons] (More Pistons - 1.6.4 - 1.4.1 build Smeagol.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        Mystcraft{0.10.12.00} [Mystcraft] (mystcraft-uni-1.6.4-0.10.12.00.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ForgeMultipart{1.0.0.244} [Forge Multipart] (ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.244.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Core{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed] (ProjectRedBase-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Transportation{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Transportation] (ProjectRedMechanical-BETA-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Exploration{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Exploration] (ProjectRedWorld-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        TConstruct{1.6.X_1.5.3dev} [Tinkers' Construct] (TConstruct_mc1.6.4_1.5.3d3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Compatibility{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Compatibility] (ProjectRedCompat-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Integration{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Integration] (ProjectRedIntegration-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Transmission{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Transmission] (ProjectRedIntegration-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Illumination{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Illumination] (ProjectRedLighting-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ProjRed|Expansion{4.3.5.30} [ProjectRed-Expansion] (ProjectRedMechanical-BETA-1.6.4-4.3.5.30.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        staircraftmod{1.6} [Staircraft] (Staircraftmod-16---164-Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        modJ_StarMiner{0.9.6} [StarMiner] (Starminer164-0_9_6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        iChunUtil{2.4.0} [iChunUtil] (util^iChunUtil2.4.0.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        weaponmod{1.6.2 v1.13.6} [Balkon's WeaponMod] (WeaponMod.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        WR-CBE|Core{1.4.0.7} [WR-CBE Core] (WR-CBE 1.4.0.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        WR-CBE|Addons{1.4.0.7} [WR-CBE Addons] (WR-CBE 1.4.0.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        WR-CBE|Logic{1.4.0.7} [WR-CBE Logic] (WR-CBE 1.4.0.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        McMultipart{1.0.0.244} [Minecraft Multipart Plugin] (ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.244.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        ForgeMicroblock{1.0.0.244} [Forge Microblocks] (ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.244.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
        TConstruct Environment: DO NOT REPORT THIS CRASH! Unsupported mods in environment: optifine
        Launched Version: 1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965
        LWJGL: 2.9.0
        OpenGL: GeForce GTX 680/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.4.0, NVIDIA Corporation
        Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
        Type: Client (map_client.txt)
        Resource Pack: Default
        Current Language: English (US)
        Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
        Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like TConstruct doesn't support Optifine. Try getting rid of Optifine, and see if that helps. ("TConstruct Environment: DO NOT REPORT THIS CRASH! Unsupported mods in environment: optifine")

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and at the same time wierd. I've used TConstruct before with OptiFine good before. Latest patch I did was Natura, from the same modder and Sphax texture packs for both mods.

Comment: Except that Unionhawk’s answer couldn’t have been correct because as PixelToe said, they’ve used TCon and OF together before. Plus, the stack-error is unrelated to the conflict. It was just a coincidence that it worked. Most likely, PixelToe changed or removed the config folder, causing modifications to the mods to reset.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the crash log, Tinkers' Construct does not support Optifine:

> TConstruct Environment: DO NOT REPORT THIS CRASH! Unsupported mods in environment: optifine

Removing Optifine should fix this particular issue.